# Apply decorators to third-party classes

Tags: typescript

I've got a DI container class which requires the classes to resolve to be decorated with an `@Injectable()` decorator, in order for the decorated class to emit metadata and for further configuration (pretty much like Angular DI works, https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).

In order to register third-party classes to my container I need to apply the `@Injectable` decorator to classes which I'm not able to modify. Think of something like a logger library installed in node_modules which I'd like to have in my container.

Is there a way to apply decorators to third-party classes? I'm thinking of something like:

```
import {Container, Injectable} from "./Container";
import {Logger} from "@vendor/logger";

const container = new Container();

container.register(Logger, { useClass: Logger }); // not possible, since Logger is not decorated
container.register(decorate(Logger, Injectable), { useClass: Logger }); // something like this, which would allow for decorating a class with a certain decorator
```

The only solution I can think of now is to create a decorated proxy class which extends from the real logger class. But proxying all third party classes seems like a lot of overhead.

Any other ideas?

Edit to give some more information:

The `@Injectable` decorator is required because non-decorated classes do not emit metadata (which would make it impossible for the container to read and resolve its dependencies). It's simply implemented by adding a metadata key to the decorated class with a key of `__INJECTABLE` and a value of `true` - whenever new services are registered in the container it checks if the `__INJECTABLE` flag is set and throws an error otherwise.

Here's an example of a proxy class:

```
import {Container, Injectable} from "./Container";
import {Logger as ParentLogger} from "@vendor/logger";

// Proxy
@Injectable()
class Logger extends ParentLogger {
}

const container = new Container();
container.register(Logger, { useClass: Logger });
```

This *should* work I guess, but would require to create proxies for pretty much every third party class.

Comment: It might be possible to create the proxies via the `decorate` function, but it's not clear from your description how `Injectable` is used. Maybe if you could provide an example of a manually created proxy, you might get some feedback on how to do it automatically.

Comment: Added some more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `decorate` function can look something like this:

```js
function Injectable() { return (_: any) => {} }

class ParentLogger { }

// Proxy
@Injectable()
class Logger extends ParentLogger {
}

function decorate<T extends { new(...args: any[]): any }>(sourceClass: T): T{
    @Injectable()
    class destinationClass extends sourceClass
    {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
        }
    }
    return destinationClass;
}

const DecoratedLogger = decorate(ParentLogger);
```

Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABASTAKwKbQIYCMA2GAFAJSIDeiAThlCFUkQPoBci2YAnmQLwB8FAL6JBAKFER82AM7TEABWw0wUADJwA5hoxUKI8QHoDCqnAAenUQAFUmHAWIkJU2YnVadiDGagYwAEzlFZTVNbV1yUTFRUEhYBER-LDgqbF8AHgAVLx8-QL0wDAB3IgA6cqUNaTYOTgBtAF0SGq4RPiJpOHoIDABhF2rETOahyMRxxBt0LCg8QlJRCcRJGTkk6VgwNPgwftWc3wC5Tu6%20gcWJsaWJiAQNqhBoFLKKqiqW%20qaKC%20vr6RAAA46F6lSrSEgAbh%201zES1hExodAYiQwGxgW3iuwGUOitzAG0QABFkqlfP53OFEDwUbdScRgn5Qh4qJDREA).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this here if anyone else encounters this. I had issues with third party apps using other third party base classes and ended up calling this.

```
decorate(injectable(), Object.getPrototypeOf(Events.EventEmitter));
```

I also found this flag after that will disable this check so you do not even need to make the base classes from third party libraries injectable. It will still work without them being Injectable

```
const container = new Container({ skipBaseClassChecks: true });
```